# Not able to get sockets to connect

Tags: python, python-3.x

Server.py

```
import socket

# create a socket object
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

# get local machine name
host = socket.gethostname()

port = 443

# bind to the port
serversocket.bind((host, port))

# queue up to 5 requests
serversocket.listen(5)

while True:
    # establish a connection
    clientsocket,addr = serversocket.accept()

    print("Got a connection from %s" % str(addr))
    msg = clientsocket.recv(1024)
    print(msg.decode('ascii'))
    clientsocket.close()
```

Network_Class.py

```
import socket
from Registry_Class import Registry_Class


class Network_class:

    def __init__(self):
        self.socket_handler = None

    def socket_open(self, server_ip, server_port):
        try:
            self.socket_handler = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            host = server_ip
            port = int(server_port)
            self.socket_handler.connect((host, port))
        except:
            # Make actual exceptions here but this is just a place holder
            return False

    def socket_writer(self, data):
        msg = str(data)
        self.socket_handler.send(msg.encode('ascii'))

    def socket_reader(self):
        data = self.socket_handler.recv(1024)
        data = data.decode('ascii')
        return data

    def socket_close(self):
        self.socket_handler.close()
```

Main.py

```
from Registry_Class import Registry_Class
from Network_Class import Network_class


Reg_Obj = Registry_Class()
Net_Obj = Network_class()
Reg_Obj.set_sub_key()
guid_value = Reg_Obj.get_reg(name="AgentGuid")
ServerIP = Reg_Obj.get_reg(name="Server")
ServerPort = Reg_Obj.get_reg(name="Port")
if guid_value and ServerIP and ServerPort:
    Net_Obj.socket_open(server_ip=ServerIP, server_port=ServerPort)
    Net_Obj.socket_writer(guid_value)
else:
    reg_start_check = Reg_Obj.reg_start()
    if reg_start_check:
        print("This succeeded in making the registry values to start")
    else:
        print("Was not able to create the registry values. I might not have rights.")
```

Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/beckc/PycharmProjects/Smaug/Client/main.py", line 13, in <module>
    Net_Obj.socket_writer(guid_value)
  File "C:\Users\beckc\PycharmProjects\Smaug\Client\Network_Class.py", line 22, in socket_writer
    self.socket_handler.send(msg.encode('ascii'))
OSError: [WinError 10057] A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
```

I have already tried in powershell to do a test-netconnection and I am able to connect to this socket. For some reason I can never get this method to connect. Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You suppress excep  tions when `self.socket_handler.connect((host, port))`. Try printing the exception to see if you get more information. You may have to allow pycharm through your firewall to get the connection to work.

Comment: No idea what happened but it is working now. I just had to restart pycharm and re-run server.py.